# Sed script to AWK

Tags: sed

I don't do this often, and when I do it is always time sensitive.  I have the sed script below that extracts a number pattern from over a million files.    I need to pike this to AWK, so when the matched pattern is found it prints the file name where it was found.   Line number would be great but not being greedy.

**desired output**

Filename1 000-323423-33

Filename2 000-323423-33

Filename3 000-323423-33

I have tried various methods but nothing has worked, can anyone with more experienced provide proper guidance?   thank you in advance!

```
#!/bin/sh

#shopt -s nullglob
FILES=/mnt/c/temp/1/*.txt
for f in $FILES

do
    echo "Processing $f"
    sed -nr \
        -e '/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}/{
            s/.*([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/
            G
            p 
            }' $f 
done
```

Comment: _desired output_ - what's the input then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your task is what `grep` is doing. If you really don't want the colons, replace them with space using `tr`, assuming colons don't exist into filenames.

```
grep -Eon '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}' *.txt | tr ':' ' '
```

Output will be like:

```
file1 10 000-323423-33
file2 20 000-323423-34
file3 30 000-323423-35
file3 31 000-323423-36
```

Answer (score 1):

@thanasisp is right, `grep` is ideal for this job.

With awk, you can write

```bsh
awk -v OFS=, '
  match($0, /[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}/) {
    print FILENAME, FNR, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  }
' /mnt/c/temp/1/*.txt
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

With that many files, you might get an "argument list too long" error. That's when you need `find`

```bsh
find /mnt/c/temp/1/ -type f -name '*.txt' -exec awk -v OFS=, '
  match($0, /[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}/) {
    print FILENAME, FNR, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
  }
' '{}' +
```

Comment: Most excellent - i tried Thanasisp solution on portion of the files (about 100k), was able to take the result and massage it further with Power Query .  Going to try the find/AWk method to see if  one solution is faster then other, some file s are 300MB, want to be be able to perfect this.   Most appreciative, many thanks.